# How do I write the init function from Haskell in Prolog

Tags: prolog, code-translation

```
init :: [a] -> [a]
init [_] = []
init (x:xs) = x : init xs
```

> Formulate the appropriate Prolog rule `init(Xs,Ys)` which is true if
> (and only if) `Ys` is the initial part of `Xs`.
>
> That is, the query
> `init([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4]).` would evaluate to `true`, or the query
> `init([1,2,3,4,5],Ys).` would give `Ys = [1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: Take a look at [`append/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3) and its source (click on the upper right (:-) button) The "if (and only if)" requirement is sadly impossible to satisfy. "if" will have to do.

Comment: `init(Xs, Ys) :- append(Ys, [_], Xs).`

Comment: Why is this question closed when it already has two perfectly valid answers?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I don't know either. it could be that no effort was shown by OP whatever, or that it looks like cut-and-paste homework assignment (which at first I didn't notice). but  the reason for closure doesn't seem to apply. (or perhaps what's meant is that the "details" of _the OP's effort_ are missing...)  I've removed the haskell tag so it doesn't bother the haskell community that much, so it can be voted to reopen.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: Look at the closers. All of the  [tag:haskell] tag.

Comment: @false I guess the question quality must be higher in the Haskell universe..

Comment: @DavidTonhofer or the tolerance threshold is lower.

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward translation of your Haskell code into Prolog code is:

```
init([_], []) :- !.
init([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
   init(Xs, Ys).
```

Results with the straightforward translation:

```
?- init([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4]).
true.

?- init([1,2,3,4,5], Ys).
Ys = [1, 2, 3, 4].

?- init([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3]). % does not work properly!
false.
```

However, as it was defined, predicate `init/2` does not works properly (since a list can have several different *initial parts*, or *prefixes*). Thus, a slightly better translation is:

```
init(_, []).            % assuming that first argument is any list!

init([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
   init(Xs, Ys).
```

Results with modified translation:

```
?- init([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4]).
true.

?- init([1,2,3,4,5], Ys).
Ys = [] ;
Ys = [1] ;
Ys = [1, 2] ;
Ys = [1, 2, 3] ;
Ys = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
Ys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

?- init([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3]).
true.
```

Comment: `init([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3]).` results in `false` with and without the cut, as it should. (?)

Comment: Will Ness, I think that the correct answer for the query ```init([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3]).``` should be ```true```, since ```[1,2,3]``` is an initial part of ```[1,2,3,4,5]```. But, as I said before, the straightforward translation (with cut) results in ```false```. Thus, I have suggested a modification of the  straightforward translation (without cut and assuming that the first argument is any list) that produces the correct answer.

Comment: no, this is about the specific function as it is defined in Haskell. it is equivalent to `init(A,B):- append(B,[_],A).`. it is not  general prefix function. :)

Comment: I understand that the function specification is what it should do, not how it is coded. Thus, the especification is  **Formulate the appropriate Prolog rule init(Xs,Ys) which is true if (and only if) Ys is the initial part of Xs**, not the given Haskell code. Anyway, in my answer I have presented both versions: that resulting from the direct translation of the given code an also that resulting from the specification.

Comment: I think whoever asked the question should decide which version is best for their needs.

Comment: that depends on the meaning of "initial part". words could mean anything. `init` is an existing library function in Haskell, and is coded as shown in the question. :) the OP's example "the query `init([1,2,3,4,5],Ys).` would give `Ys = [1,2,3,4]`" also conforms with  its accepted -- in Haskell -- meaning.

Comment: Yes, that is true! And it is up to the user who asked the question to decide what is the corret meaning.

Comment: I think it is up to every individual to decide that for themself. :)

Comment: I mostly agree with you!

Comment: In any case, `init` is such a badly chosen word.

Answer (score 1):

First transform your definition into an [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) form:

```hs
init [_] = []
init (x:xs) = rs where { rs = x:ys ; ys = init xs }
```

(there's no need nor place for the type signature in Prolog translation).

Now do the syntactical hocus-pocus:

```
init([_] , []).
init([X|XS] , RS)  :-    RS = [X|YS],    init( XS, YS) .
```

Since in Haskell only the *first* matching clause fires, i.e. each clause has an implicit cut after it, add the cut:

```
initc([_] , []) :- !.
initc([X|XS] , RS)  :-   RS = [X|YS],    initc( XS, YS) .
```

Done.

Comment: This cut hurts.

Comment: @false I've removed it in the meantime, but could you give me specifics as to where and why, please? I tried examples with and without it, can't see the problem.

Comment: I think I'm going to restore it since  it _is_ implicit in Haskell, which is a _functional_ language.

Comment: But functional languages have no problem with steadfastness. Yet, Prolog with cuts does.

Comment: @false thanks for the clarification. functional languages have no problem with steadfastness as they have no such concept. for a Prolog code to emulate a functional code it is understood that the "input" variables will always be already instantiated, ground. the query `X=[1,2], initCut(X,_)` is what corresponds to the Haskell call `let {_ = init [1,2]} in ()` but the problematic query `initCut(X,_), X=[1,2]`  does not correspond to any Haskell call, so one could reasonably argue it ought to be out of consideration here as well.